# Valuation on a Dedekind domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we take $R$ a Dedekind domain and $p$ a non zero prime ideal of $R$, we denote by $v_p$ the valuation of its quotient field $K$ with valuation ring $R_p=(R\setminus p)^{-1}R$. How can I show that for almost $p$, for $a \in K^*$ we have $v_p(a)=0$ ?

Comment: What do you mean "...that for all $\;p\;$" ...? The prime ideal $\;p\;$ is given **and fixed** from the beginning...

Comment: It was to introduce my notations.

Comment: But it's false!  $v_p(a)=0$ means that  $a\in R_p^\times$

Comment: I don't know it's writen in the Cassels & Frolich that it is true for almost all $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean that given $a\in K^*$ then $v_p(a)=0$ for all but finitely many prime ideals $p$.

Write $a=b/c$ where $b$, $c$ are nonzero elements of $R$, and observe
that $b$ and $c$ lie in only finitely many prime ideals of $R$.

Comment: Yes okay thanks ! By the way my goal is to read an article of Shinichi Mochizuki and my advisor told me to read Cassels & Frolich to learn some theory first but this book is not really easy to ready for a beginner like me, do you know any other books I should read ?